# unable to render vuejs component after installing Argon Dashboard for laravel to my laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, argon

i'm having active project and inside all the vuejs components are working fine , but when installed  Argon Dashboard for laravel to my laravel project . My VueJs Components are not showing , i have added js/app.js to my layout/app.blade.php but still its not generating component view inside blade view please help

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: ok i figured out it was missing id as App inside layout/app.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured out it was missing id as App inside layout/app.blade.php